# Getting the order of reordered UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to get reordered index of cells into an array.

In `viewDidLoad`

```
cell.showsReorderControl = YES;
arrayTag = [NSMutableArray array];
```

//Saving indexPath.row as cell.tag while creating the cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
 {
   .....

   cell.tag = indexPath.row;
   NSString *strCellTag = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",cell.tag];
   if(![arrayTag containsObject:strCellTag])
   {
      [arrayTag addObject:strCellTag];
   }
   return cell;
 }
```

//I'm not sure if this is the right way, but below I'm trying to save the changes to the array.

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath
{
    [arrayTag replaceObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",proposedDestinationIndexPath.row]];
    [arrayTag replaceObjectAtIndex:proposedDestinationIndexPath.row withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",sourceIndexPath.row]];

    return proposedDestinationIndexPath;
}
```

To verify I `NSLog`:

```
- (IBAction)doneButton:(id)sender
{
    NSLog (@"Number of Objects in Array %i", arrayTag.count);

    for (NSString *obj in arrayTag){
        NSLog(@"From ArrayTag obj: %@", obj);
    }   
}
```

`NSLog` WITHOUT moving cells results as expected.

```
2013-07-10 17:50:47.291 MyApp[1634:c07] Number of Objects in Array 7
2013-07-10 17:50:47.292 MyApp[1634:c07] From ArrayTag obj: 0
2013-07-10 17:50:47.292 MyApp[1634:c07] From ArrayTag obj: 1
2013-07-10 17:50:47.292 MyApp[1634:c07] From ArrayTag obj: 2
2013-07-10 17:50:47.292 MyApp[1634:c07] From ArrayTag obj: 3
2013-07-10 17:50:47.293 MyApp[1634:c07] From ArrayTag obj: 4
2013-07-10 17:50:47.293 MyApp[1634:c07] From ArrayTag obj: 5
2013-07-10 17:50:47.293 MyApp[1634:c07] From ArrayTag obj: 6
```

`NSLog` AFTER moving/shuffling cells appears to be wrong.  I'm not getting unique values.

```
2013-07-10 17:51:55.329 MyApp[1634:c07] Number of Objects in Array 7
2013-07-10 17:51:55.330 MyApp[1634:c07] From ArrayTag obj: 4
2013-07-10 17:51:55.330 MyApp[1634:c07] From ArrayTag obj: 5
2013-07-10 17:51:55.330 MyApp[1634:c07] From ArrayTag obj: 5
2013-07-10 17:51:55.330 MyApp[1634:c07] From ArrayTag obj: 5
2013-07-10 17:51:55.331 MyApp[1634:c07] From ArrayTag obj: 6
2013-07-10 17:51:55.331 MyApp[1634:c07] From ArrayTag obj: 6
2013-07-10 17:51:55.331 MyApp[1634:c07] From ArrayTag obj: 4
```

Q:  Why am I not getting new unique values after reordering?  How do I get the new order of cells saved in the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found a solution that works in Apple's Docs.

Declare a NSMutableArray property .h or .m: `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *arrayTag;`

Synthesize it: `@synthesize arrayTag;`

Initialize it in `viewDidLoad` `arrayTag = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

Here is the code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{
    NSString *stringToMove = [arrayTag objectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
    [arrayTag removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
    [arrayTag insertObject:stringToMove atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
}
```

Link to Apple's site: Listing 8-2: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/ManageReorderRow/ManageReorderRow.html

Answer (score 5):

### Delegate and DataSource clarification

You shouldn't modify the data behind the tableView during:

```
-tableView:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:toProposedIndexPath:
```

This method gets called when the user is just hovering the cell above the others, and thus, it causes multiple calls to this function while the cell is being dragged.

The key here is that, that method is part of `UITableViewDelegate`, **it's not meant to modify data**, but change appearence of the tableView, and it's just there to do that "sliding" animation when the cell is hovering. The returned value determines where the cell should be animated to.

What you should do, is perform the changes when the user has commited them, that happens when you get the call into the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol method:

```
-tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:
```

This is when the user has released the cell and it's on place, and it occurs once per drag & drop.

As a general rule of thumb, whatever is on the `UITableViewDelegate` is for shows, and what's on `UITableViewDataSource` is for the real data.

### Modifying the Model

#### Swapping

Swapping or exchanging, is the easiest case ([**A**, B, C, **D**] => [**D**, B, C, **A**]), and there's a very convenient method for that:

```
[arrayTag exchangeObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row withObjectAtIndex:toIndexPath.row];
```

Swift

```
let f = fromIndexPath.row, t = toIndexPath.row
(array[f], array[t]) = (array[t], array[f])
```

#### Insertion

Insertion is a little more tricky and verbose ([**A**, B, C, **D**] => [B, C, **D**, **A**]). The important thing is making the changes so they don't affect each other.

```
id obj = [arrayTag objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
[arrayTag removeObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
[arrayTag insertObject:obj atIndex:toIndexPath.row];
```

Swift

```
let obj = array.removeAtIndex(fromIndexPath.row)
array.insert(newElement: obj, atIndex: toIndexPath.row)
```

Comment: Thank you for your clarification!  Q1.  So is my code okay (before the Edit), I just need to move it to -tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath: ?  Q2.  I only need to know the codes once the user dismisses the Modal View.  Is there a method that I can call in my prepareForSegue that gets the tags of the new ordered cells?

Comment: Q1: Sure, but it's better if you use the exchange method I posted above, it's much more simple.

Q2: Well, the arrayTag should contain the re-ordered tags, right? If you moved the first row to the last it should contain `[1, 2, 3, 4, 0]` for example, isn't that good enough for what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thank you so very much!  I had been struggling with this for a day now!

Comment: Problem: While unique index is taken care, I'm having issues with incorrect results.  i.e.  If at first 0 is moved to 6 the result is [1,2,3,4,5,6,0] and then if 1 is moved to where now 0  is, the array should become [2,3,4,5,6,0,1].  However,  my NSLog shows up as [5,1,2,3,4,6,0]. I'll edit the post and show you the log.

Comment: Damn, I was out for a few days. Good that you found out for yourself, yeah, the exchange didn't help you in your case, as you wanted the values inserted in between, not exchanged. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

you if you want to swap two objects you must hold an object in a temp location:

psuedocode

```
arr = [a,b,c]

//to swap(0,2)...

tmp = arr[2]

[arr replaceObjectAtIndex: 2 withObject: arr[0]]

[arr replaceObjectAtIndex: 0 withObject:tmp];
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I have made an Edit.  Can you please review it and tell me if that's what you're suggesting?  Sorry, I'm new.  Thanks.

Comment: @user1107173 no you are replacing the object with the NSIndexPath  * object rather than the old spot in the array.