# How to save rearranged table view position

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a table view which can be rearranged by pressing edit and dragging the cell into a new position. The problem i have is when the app is closed or you go to a different view controller and then go back to the table view, the cell has gone back to its original position. Here is my code to enable the rearrange:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
    [arrayData removeObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
    [arrayData removeObjectAtIndex:toIndexPath.row];
}

// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;

}
```

Comment: Check out this answer for a proper guidance.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17593068/getting-the-order-of-reordered-uitableviewcells

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
[arrayData removeObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
[arrayData removeObjectAtIndex:toIndexPath.row];
```

To something like this:

```
NSString *stringToMove /*or whatever*/ = [arrayData objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
[arrayData removeObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
[arrayData insertObject:stringToMove atIndex:toIndexPath.row];
```

Basically, you're not re-inserting the data, you're just removing it.

To keep the order when the view controller is reloaded, you'll need to make sure the array is saved somewhere. Saving it to a `plist` file could work, for example.

Reference: [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageReorderRow/ManageReorderRow.html)

Comment: I have added that code but it still doesn't work. I am using core data to save the information, could this be causing a problem?

Comment: Are you pulling your info in from core data before reloading the table view?

Comment: I reload the table view in the viewdidappear, because the user enters the data from another view controller then when the table view appears it loads the data.

Comment: Well the point is, you need to 1) make sure you're saving the data when it's modified (so in your `moveRowAtIndexPath` method) and 2) make sure it's in the correct order before calling `reloadData` wherever you call it.